# How can I show skip to next feature on antd pagination?

Tags: reactjs, pagination, antd

How to show the number of pages with 3 dots if number of pages is less than or equal to 7. I tried using `showLessItem` but it does not fix the issue.

```
<Pagination
    onShowSizeChange
    current={1}
    pageSize={10}
    total={64}
    showLessItems
    onChange={handlePaginationChange}
  />

const handlePaginationChange = (pageNumber: any) => {
setMinIndex((pageNumber - 1) * elementsPerPage);
setMaxIndex(pageNumber * elementsPerPage);
```

};

current UI breaks into two lines.
[image]

So, I want UI having `1 2 3 4 ... 7`, similar to below screenshot.
[image]